# Eclipse does not recognize existing resolved Maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have m2 plugin in Ecplipse 3.8.0 and a project that has maven dependencies inside. Local .m2 folder has the correct version of the dependency, pom.xml looks correctly but Dependencies tab when opening the pom.xml in Eclipse tells "Failed to read artifact descriptor.." error. Also I get missing artifact error on the Problems section on Eclipse.

Where does the m2-plugin or Eclipse read those dependencies, if they show up correctly on pom.xml and the correcponding jar is at .m2 folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed check from "Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories" option and that made the trick.

Comment: Thanks @user503413 about pointing me on correct direction when answering about check for settings. My +1 came for that.

Comment: Where is that option?

Comment: `Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories`

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse produces quite a lot of problems when it comes to M2. What I do to get rid of this problems is to clean the project(Project > Clean...), use an external maven (Window > Preferences > Installations > ...) for building purposes and from the maven settings of a project I Update Project configuration (Right click on the project > Maven > Update project ...).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I removed check from "Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories" option and that made the trick. Was this the tap you meant?

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution. Not exactly sure I know what tap you refer to, though.

Comment: I did all this, didn't work, but then i closed the project(right click on project >> close project) in eclipse and opened it back again and it worked. Seems like an eclipse bug.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse will sometimes need a kick like user503413 says (and a restart), but sometimes it's also right: make sure that in `$HOME/.m2/repository/` you indeed have the dependencies you want (that's where maven, and therefore m2eclipse through maven) will put them. If they *are* there, make sure the pom makes sense. Fix if needed, and... then clean up and restart eclipse just in case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem today with "provided"-scoped dependencies. Solution was to set the "compile"-scope for all dependencies, then build once and after that, recover the original scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when my project is a Java project but not a Maven project. Close project, delete (don't check the box to delete files), and then re-import the project as an Existing Maven Project. I think this is a common way the problem occurs.