# Eclipse-Maven Forcefully Overwrites Java Version Set Every Update Project

Tags: maven-3, java-11, maven-eclipse-plugin, oomph, eclipse-2021-09

## What are the details of your problem?

Why does Eclipse's Maven's plug-in overwrite the Java version set with a lower version?

When the Eclipse Maven-plugin runs `Project Update...`, the [JDK gets switched from 11 to 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509928/java-version-automatically-change-to-java-1-5-after-maven-update).
This causes Java version 11+ stuff in the code to break and unable to compile or run.
When I try to switch the project back to 11+ and compile, the Maven dependency imports break.
To get the Maven packaged packages from Nexus, I end up running `Project Update` to resolve.
This causes Eclipse-Maven to set the JDK to 8. The project needs Java-11 or higher.

What needs to happen to allow the Maven dependencies to resolve and the correct Java version be used?

### Environment Versions:

1. Eclipse: 2023-06 (4.28.0)
2. Java-8: 1.8.0_301
3. Java-11: 11.0.15.1
4. Maven: 3.9.1/3.9.100.20230519-1558 (EMBEDDED)
5. OS: Windows 10

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

1. Running Maven `mvn compile` , `mvn install` , `mvn package`, `mvn clean compile` and any other combinations anyways

   1. Result: Maven Build Failed

      1. [Project has been able to run before even when the Eclipse-Maven-plugin did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807869/eclipse-does-not-recognize-existing-resolved-maven-dependencies)
2. Changing the [Eclipse-Project-Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949928/eclipse-project-properties-dont-show-build-path): `Java Build Path` , `Java Code Style` , `Java Compiler` ; to be JDK-11

   1. [Java Build Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333582/java-eclipse-build-path)

      1. Editing the JRE-Selection with its `System library` selection: `Execution environment` , `Alternate JRE` , and `Workspace default JRE` (which I set with the Eclipse-Preferences)

         1. Result: Maps, Lists, and other Java imports break
      2. Removing and Readding the `JRE System Library`

         1. Result: Maps, Lists, and other Java imports break
      3. Checkbox-Selecting in `Order and Export` for `Maven Dependencies` and `JRE System Library`

         1. Result: Nothing notable to the situation changed
   2. [Java Code Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601793/how-do-i-modify-eclipse-code-formatting)

      1. Enabling and Disabling explicit `Enable project specific settings` to Java-11

         1. Result: No notable changes
   3. [Java Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127132/how-do-i-change-the-default-eclipse-oxygen-compiler-compliance-level-from-9-to-1)

      1. Enabling and Disabling explicit `Enable project specific settings` to Java-11

         1. Result: Maps, Lists, and other Java imports break
3. Adding the [POM Java Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p) in the `properties.java.version` and `properties.maven.compiler.[source, target]`

   1. Result: No Change
4. Setting `JAVA_HOME` is [jdk-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481756/java-version-shows-java-8-while-java-11-is-installed)

   1. Result: no change (correct location)
5. Reverting back the [Eclipse-Maven changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819808/11705601) in `.classpath` XML for its `classpath.classpathentry` for the `org.eclipse.jdt.launching` to be `<attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>` and no reference to `JavaSE-1.8`

   1. Result: Eclipse-Maven reverts this back
6. Editing `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` to explicitly be Java 11 and/or remove references to "1.8"

   1. Result: Eclipse-Maven reverts this back
7. Checking [Oomph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395802/update-the-jdk-path-of-eclipse-installed-by-oomph-setup) wasn't setting the Java version in `org.eclipse.oomph.setup/setup/user.setup`

   1. Result: No reference to Java or its versions

Comment: How does your pom file look like?

Comment: @khmarbaise I've tried to both add an explicit set to `<source>11</source> <target>11</target>`  and tried removing to have the workspace and/or project/maven resolve with inference and defaulting.

Comment: Description does not help.. show the pom file... do you use the properties? configuration only for plugins ?